# Moq verify a specific exception is thrown and caught

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I have a method to create a queue if necessary.
In case the queue already exists the method returns false, if the creation is successful true.

I'd like to test the scenario when the queue does not exist during the `QueueExists` check, but is created by another process before getting to the `CreateQueueAsync` call.

I have my product code:

```
internal bool QueueExists(string queueName)
{
    var allQueues = ManagementClient.GetQueuesAsync().Result;
    if (!allQueues.Any(q => q.Path.Equals(queueName)))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public bool CreateQueueIfNotExists(string queueName, bool requiresSession)
{
    if (!QueueExists(queueName))
    {
        try
        {
            ManagementClient.CreateQueueAsync(queueDescription).Wait();
            return true;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            Exception e = ae.GetBaseException();

            // If the queue already exists then no additional action is needed.
            if (e is MessagingEntityAlreadyExistsException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(e);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My Nunit test
The `CreateQueueAsync` will be called twice because the `GetQueuesAsync` will always return an empty list.

```
[Test]
public void QueueCreation_MessagingEntityAlreadyExistsException_IsCatched()
{
    // Given            
    var managementClientMock = new Mock<ManagementClient>(connectionString) { CallBase = true };
    managementClientMock.Setup(m => m.GetQueuesAsync(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<System.Threading.CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult<IList<QueueDescription>>(new List<QueueDescription>()));
    QueueFactory queueFactory = new QueueFactory(managementClientMock.Object);

    Assert.That(queueFactory.CreateQueueIfNotExists(alreadyExistsQueue, true), Is.True, 
"First queue creation did not returned true.");
    Assert.That(queueFactory.CreateQueueIfNotExists(alreadyExistsQueue, true), Is.False, 
"First queue creation did not returned false.");
    managementClientMock.Verify(m => m.CreateQueueAsync(It.IsAny<QueueDescription>(), It.IsAny<System.Threading.CancellationToken>()), Times.Exactly(2));
}
```

This is quite okay, but I want to check whether an aggregate exception is thrown AND CATCHED the second time and `MessagingEntityAlreadyExistsException` is the inner exception. So the `ExpectedException` and `Assert.Throws` won't work here, the exception is caught in the product method.

I there a way to do this with Moq?

Comment: What is the logic for `QueueExists(..)` function? And if that condition checks that the queue does not exist before creating one, how is the exception thrown?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear.

Comment: Updated with the `QueueExists` method. The test basically covers the issue, and tests whether a `MessagingEntityAlreadyExistsException` is thrown. However I'm curious is there a Moq feature to verify that the mocked object throwed a specific exception dispite the fact that it is caught in the product code.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question - I'm not aware of anything within Moq that does this.  However are you able to get what you are looking for by splitting the problem in two (apologies if I've misunderstood)?

First, separately test `ManagementClient`, verify that calling it twice with the same queue raises an aggregate exception, and that `MessagingEntityAlreadyExistsException` is the inner exception.

Second, test the code belonging to the method in your example with a stub ManagementClient that throws an aggregate exception containing the same inner exception when called.  In that test, verify that no exception was thrown (i.e. the exception was caught and not rethrown).